# Failed to load receiver assembly

Tags: assembly-references

I'm working with 3 WFE, I'm, trying to deploy a solution with 2 master pages, also with a feature that will help us to change the master when we active it or deactivate it.

The solutions has been updated, so the way I'm deploying the solution is with PowerShell using `install-spsolution` command.

The solutions deploys to 2 out of 3 WFE, the Solution management display error message on the third:

> WFEXXXXX : Failed to load receiver assembly "MySharePointProject
>   Feature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" for feature "Custom Master
>   Page_MPChangeFeature1" (ID: 9d71c1af-f03f-473b-a2a7-f8037af369c5).:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MySharePointProject Feature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one
>   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'MySharePointProject Feature, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral'     at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)     at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging.  To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> NDHWQ50077 : Failed to load receiver assembly "MySharePointProject
>   Feature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" for feature "Custom Master
>   Page_MPChangeFeature1" (ID: 9d71c1af-f03f-473b-a2a7-f8037af369c5).:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MySharePointProject Feature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one
>   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File
>   name: 'MySharePointProject Feature, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' 
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)     at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)     at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging.  To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I've browsed into the servers looking for this Registry Value `"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog"` but none of the servers has the value, I mean the entrie is not even there, meaning the value is turned off.

My first option will be to turn it on in 3 WFE, but the weird thing is the error only pops in 1 WFE.

We have deployed this very same solution in QA server and it works just fine.

- How come I got this error in only 1 WFE server and none of the 3 has the value activated?
- Could this error be caused by something else?

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to verify that the SharePoint Timer service is running properly on all servers in the farm.  Beyond that, you would need to look at Central Admin and see if the deployment of the solution generated unusual errors for the other servers.

If that all looks good then you probably need to understand the nature of the update.  Did the Strong Name change on the DLL in any way?  Even a single digit difference would make a different name.  If that changed, they you should do a full retraction of the solution followed by a redeployment of it.

It is also possible that the solution itself is relying on a reference to another file that is either not in the solution or is not installed on your production servers.

Answer (score 0):

Try signing your project with a new key:

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and choose Properties
2. Go to Signing and where it says "Choose a strong key name" select
3. (I used the same name key.snk which couldn't replace the old one and required me to remove the Read-Only attribute on the entire project folder)
4. Rebuild the solution (that's Rebuild, not Build)
5. Package the solution and try deploying again